# Проверка оплаты aaio python

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Здравия, люди, работавшие с телеграмм ботами и aaio на python, подскажите, как сделать обработчик, который будет проверять прошла ли оплата и выполнять определенный код.

Answer (score 0):

Есть уже готовая библиотека: [AaioAPI](https://pypi.org/project/AaioAPI).

Если без библиотеки хочешь, то почитай [здесь](https://wiki.aaio.io/api/informaciya-o-zakaze).

Ты получишь ответ в json формате, проверяй `status` на значение `"success"` и `"hold"` (желательно).

Comment: Спасибо большое